# Lists in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from random import randint

List = [randint(0,99) for i in range(20)]
print("%3s" % List)
List.sort()
print("%3s" % List)
```

so i've been working on this code to give me a random list of 20 inputs between 0 and 99. Did i do the print statements correctly so that it would print 20 per line with a field with of 3? Im assuming field with means xx9 or x98 etc?

Comment: `print(''.join('{:>3}'.format(n) for n in List))` or `print(''.join(format(n, '>3') for n in List))` or `print(''.join('%3s' % n for n in List))`

Answer (score 3):

No, you didn't do the print format correctly.  You have a single `%s` format, which is correct to print a string.  Adding the 3, as in `%3s`, will try to print the string in a width-3 field.  But you then pass in `List`, which isn't a string, but rather is a list.  That's okay, though, because Python knows how to print a `list` instance as a string.  It's wider than 3 so Python prints it at whatever width it works out to.  So Python prints something like this, complete with square brackets and commas:

```
[0, 4, 6, 9, 19, 19, 22, 25, 34, 41, 65, 71, 72, 74, 74, 75, 78, 79, 88, 99]
```

There are two easy ways to get the output you want.  One is to use a `for` loop and print it one value at a time, like so:

```
for n in List:
    print("%3d" % n, end='')
print()
```

By using `end=''` we are telling Python not to print a "newline" after printing our number.  Then, once the loop is done, we call `print()` by itself to print a newline.

The other easy way is to use the `.join()` method function to join together all the numbers you want to print, which will give you a single string that is exactly what you want to print.  Then just print that!

```
s = ' '.join(str(n) for n in List)
print(s)
```

I don't know if you have seen anything like this before, but there is sort of a one-line mini loop inside the `join()` call.  This is called a "generator expression" and it will generate the values we want.  `List` contains integers, and `join()` needs strings, so we convert the integers to strings so `join()` knows what to do with them.

Of course we can do it all in one line if we like:

```
print(' '.join(str(n) for n in List))
```